# Spring 4: run some initialization code before application context refresh

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-4

I am using Spring 4 (not Spring Boot) in the web application. I need to run some initialization code before any of the beans in the application context would be created. I tried to create implementation of `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer` and register it in `spring.factories` but was not picked up for some reason. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out implementing of `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer` was a right way. Because in my project I do not use Spring MVC implementation of this initializer should be registered in *web.xml* instead of *spring.factories*. Here is an example:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>my.company.MyContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If not, please post your code.

```
@Component
public class SampleBootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    ....

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        Do Something();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as the name of event suggests this listener will be called after refresh of application context. What I need is quite opposite. Actually I've already found a solution.